# Когда выбираю элемент из списка, список остается висеть а не пропадает, почему?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async() => {
  const fromCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('fromCurrency');
  const toCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('toCurrency');
  const amountInput = document.getElementById('amount');
  const convertedAmountInput = document.getElementById('convertedAmount');
  const fromCryptoDropdown = document.getElementById('fromCryptoDropdown');
  const toCryptoDropdown = document.getElementById('toCryptoDropdown');
  const fromCryptoList = document.getElementById('fromCryptoList');
  const toCryptoList = document.getElementById('toCryptoList');

  const supportedCryptos = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XMR']; // List of supported cryptocurrencies

  function renderCryptoList(cryptoList, dropdownElement) {
    cryptoList.forEach(crypto => {
      const listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-${crypto.toLowerCase()}"></i> ${crypto}`;
      listItem.dataset.cryptoName = crypto;
      listItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        dropdownElement.querySelector('input').value = crypto;
        dropdownElement.querySelector('ul').classList.remove('active');
      });
      dropdownElement.querySelector('ul').appendChild(listItem);
    });
  }

  function filterCryptoList(cryptoList, filter) {
    const regex = new RegExp(filter.toLowerCase(), 'g');

    cryptoList.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(listItem => {
      const cryptoName = listItem.dataset.cryptoName.toLowerCase();
      if (cryptoName.match(regex)) {
        listItem.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        listItem.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });

    const hasMatchingItems = [...cryptoList.querySelectorAll('li')].some(li => li.style.display === 'block');
    cryptoList.style.display = hasMatchingItems ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  fromCurrencyInput.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    fromCryptoList.classList.add('active');
    toCryptoList.classList.remove('active');
  });

  toCurrencyInput.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    toCryptoList.classList.add('active');
    fromCryptoList.classList.remove('active');
  });

  fromCurrencyInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    filterCryptoList(fromCryptoList, event.target.value);
  });

  toCurrencyInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    filterCryptoList(toCryptoList, event.target.value);
  });


  document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const clickedElement = event.target;

    if (!fromCryptoDropdown.contains(clickedElement) && !clickedElement.classList.contains('from-currency')) {
      fromCryptoList.classList.remove('active');
    }

    if (!toCryptoDropdown.contains(clickedElement) && !clickedElement.classList.contains('to-currency')) {
      toCryptoList.classList.remove('active');
    }

    if (clickedElement.tagName === 'li' && clickedElement.parentNode.classList.contains('crypto-list')) {
      fromCryptoList.classList.remove('active');
      toCryptoList.classList.remove('active');
    }
    console.log(clickedElement.parentNode)
  });

  renderCryptoList(supportedCryptos, fromCryptoDropdown);
  renderCryptoList(supportedCryptos, toCryptoDropdown);

  async function convertCurrency() {
    const fromCurrency = fromCurrencyInput.value.toUpperCase();
    const toCurrency = toCurrencyInput.value.toUpperCase();
    const amount = parseFloat(amountInput.value);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${fromCurrency}&tsyms=${toCurrency}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      const conversionRate = data[toCurrency];
      const convertedAmount = amount * conversionRate;

      convertedAmountInput.value = convertedAmount.toFixed(2);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error converting currency:', error);
    }
  }

  amountInput.addEventListener('input', convertCurrency);
  fromCurrencyInput.addEventListener('input', convertCurrency);
  toCurrencyInput.addEventListener('input', convertCurrency);
});
```

```css
.converter {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 300px;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

input,
.custom-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-dropdown input {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="converter">
  <h1>Crypto Converter</h1>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="fromCurrency">From Cryptocurrency:</label>
    <div class="custom-dropdown" id="fromCryptoDropdown">
      <input type="text" id="fromCurrency" class="from-currency" placeholder="From Currency">
      <ul id="fromCryptoList"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
    <input type="number" id="amount" step="0.01">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="toCurrency">To Cryptocurrency:</label>
    <div class="custom-dropdown" id="toCryptoDropdown">
      <input type="text" id="toCurrency" class="to-currency" placeholder="To Currency">
      <ul id="toCryptoList"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="convertedAmount">Converted Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="convertedAmount" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```